# (Android Studio, Flutter) Connection timed out when trying to run my app using real device

Tags: mysql, database, flutter, connection, localhost

I am running my app using real android device and in my flutter I used mysql1 to connect to localhost database. There is no problem when running the app on emulator but when comes to real device there is always a connection error. Below is my mysql.dart file:

```
/*This is a database configuration file*/

import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Mysql {

  static String host = '10.0.2.2',  
   

      user = 'root',  //User

      db = 'users';  //Database name

  static int port = 3306; //MySQL port number

  Mysql();

  Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(

        host: host,
        port: port,
        user: user,
        db: db);

    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);

  }

}
```

I have tried a to change the host to my localhost ip and still getting the same error. Has anyone run into the same problem?
[image: This is the error -->]

Comment: You have to be on same network. i.e for pc and mobile as you are using localhost. and try pc's ip address when you are using localhost

Comment: I did what u said and still getting the same error

Comment: do you have internet permisson in android manifest file ?

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.squiznet">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>

Comment: Do u mean this ?

Comment: Yes for main AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I think yes, and now I found that there is something to do with the firewall thingy and I have allowed permission. I think the connection now is ok, but new error comes in say that my phone is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using mysql1 ,You should  have to use sqflite in flutter https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite .

Comment: I am using mysql1 because I wanted to store data in remote database instead of storing in local deivce.